# How to get handle of controls in ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: mvvm

I am new to MVVM and need help on below scenario.

I have a Stack panel added on my view, now I have to add few controls dynamically to this stack panel through viewmodel. For this I need a handle of stack panel in my viewmodel. Can anybody please guide me how I can access stack panel in my viewmodel.

I read in other bloges that it can be done by using Dependency property. but still I am not able to find way to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'handle'? Do you mean a reference or a HWND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for your help, Here I solved the problem

In view model I have created ObservableCollection of FrameWorkElement type, which can hold any other controls which will be decided at runtime. Control can be a text box or button.

```
 Public  ObservableCollection < FrameWorkElement > Test
 {
        get{....} set{...}
 }
```

Now I can add/set any other control to Test

```
 Tets.Add(new TextBox()); Or Button , this will be decided at runtime.
```

Now bind this "Test" to ItemsControl.

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource={Biding Test}>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things to note first.  The intention of the ViewModel in the MVVM pattern is to provide separation from the View.  Therefore, your ViewModel should have no knowledge of the View itself nor the controls contained in the View.  Secondly, what you should be attempting to do is have your View bind to a property of your ViewModel (with the understanding that your ViewModel serves as the DataContext of your View).  Normally, you would bind a control's ItemsSource property to some collection in the ViewModel.  However, you will notice the StackPanel does not implement the ItemsSource dependency property.  Instead, use ItemsControl in place of your StackPanel.  I would suggest some additional reading on the MVVM pattern and the binding mechanics for additional clarification.

Comment: Thanks For u r inputs, I will definatly go through more stuff of MVVM, But as per my limited knowledge we can use Item source properry to bind some data such as binding data to list box ,grid, So I just want to confirm will it be possible to to bind different controls instate od data ,as per my requirment on perticuler event I need to create new textbox and buttons dynamically and add this in any UI container such as stack panel

Comment: You absolutely can bind controls to an ItemsControl.  I do it quite often both statically and dynamically.  It helps to think that containers can hold content, not just data.  Content can be anything (most typically a template of some sort).

Answer (score 0):

Totally agreed with Backlash, 
It seems that your ViewModel and your View are too much coupled; 
There are a bunch of resources on the Internet, but here are some I preferred:

- [Jason Dolinger presentation video on MVVM](http://www.lab49.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Jason_Dolinger_MVVM.wmv)
- [John Smith article introducing MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: Thanks For u r inputs, I will definatly go through more stuff of MVVM, But as per my limited knowledge we can use Item source properry to bind some data such as binding data to list box ,grid, So I just want to confirm will it be possible to to bind different controls instate od data ,as per my requirment on perticuler event I need to create new textbox and buttons and add this in any UI container such as stack panel.

Comment: Using MVVM pattern, you can't dynamically add controls directly from your VM in your View. However, you might add or change some data ... which are displayed differently (with new controls). But your ViewModel should never know your UI, or even how your data are displayed.  
EDIT: I'm not very clear because my English isn't fluent; If I were you, I'll just go trough some tutorials, and articles. Try to begin with some basics (bindings, templates ...) and don't be afraid to create a little project to experiment. You won't effectively learn anything if you stay with your browser.

Comment: Thanks for help Pierre-Henri Barralis

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before with a user control. I've had a collection of objects that i needed to dynamically to controls in a StackPanel. You can also do it with any control...I'll use a TextBlock in this example.

Create a data template with the control you want wrapped in a stack panel:
(MyText is a property in the object of the collection... see below)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
   <Grid Margin="0">
       <StackPanel>     
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
        </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then the key is to bind to a collection of objects using an ItemsControl:
(The collection is on your viewModel)

```
<ItemsControl   
 ItemsSource="{Binding ACollection, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 ItemTemplate=" {StaticResource MyTemplate}" Background="Transparent">
</ItemsControl>
```

So for example if there are 3 items in "ACollection" there will be 3 TextBlocks stacked on top of each other if there are 5 in the collection there will be 5 TextBlocks etc.